# Datos únicos en un data frame

Tags: r

Quiero seleccionar los datos únicos de la col2 del siguiente df conservando el resto de columnas.

```
datos2<-data.frame(
 col1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
 col2=c("AAA","BBB","AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD","BBB","BBB","CCC","DDD"),
 col3=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)
)
```

```
  col1 col2 col3
   1  AAA   10
   2  BBB   20
   3  AAA   30
   4  BBB   40
   5  CCC   50
   6  DDD   60
   7  BBB   70
   8  BBB   80
   9  CCC   90
  10  DDD  100
```

Con

```
unique(datos2$col2)
```

puedo quedarme con los datos únicos de la col2, pero quiero mantener las col1 y 3

El resultado esperado podría ser

```
  col1 col2 col3
   1  AAA   10
   2  BBB   20
   5  CCC   50
   6  DDD   60
```

He probado con

datos2[datos2$col2==unique(datos2$col2),]

Pero no funciona.

###############################

DF con NAS

```
datos2<-data.frame(
 col1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
 col2=c("AAA","BBB","AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD","BBB","BBB","CCC","DDD"),
 col3=c(10,20,30,40,NA,60,70,80,90,100),
 col4=c(NA,20,NA,40,50,60,70,80,90,100), 
 col5=c(NA,NA,NA,4,5,6,NA,NA,90,100)
)
```

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
1     1  AAA   10   NA   NA
2     2  BBB   20   20   NA
3     3  AAA   30   NA   NA
4     4  BBB   40   40    4
5     5  CCC   NA   50    5
6     6  DDD   60   60    6
7     7  BBB   70   70   NA
8     8  BBB   80   80   NA
9     9  CCC   90   90   90
10   10  DDD  100  100  100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No funciona por que al seleccionar mediante `datos2$col2==unique(datos2$col2)` en definitiva, estas recuperando todas las filas dónde `col2` sea alguno de los valores únicos, y lo que necesitas es que las filas sean una sola por grupo, digamos por ejemplo, la primera.

Esto básicamente es un agrupamiento por `col2` y la recuperación de la primer fila de cada grupo:

```
aggregate(. ~ col2, datos2, head, 1, na.action = na.pass)
```

En este caso, agrupamos todas las columnas por `col2`, indicado mediante la fórmula `. ~ col2`, del `data.frame` `datos2`, y aplicamos a cada grupo la función `head` con el parámetro 1. En caso de contar con grupos con valore `NA`, para no perderlos, incorporamos a la llamada `na.action = na.pass`

Comment: añado un df a la pregunta donde no sale la "AAA" y no entiendo el motivo

Comment: Vale, creo que se salta la "AAA", por tener NAS en el resto de columnas, selecciona el primer elemento ( "BBB" fila4 ) que no tiene NAS. La duda es que hacer en este caso.

Comment: No, es un buen punto. Hay que agregar al aggregate el parámetro `na.action = na.pass`